# SharePoint 2010 WebPart - Prevent jQuery code from running multiple times when Editing WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, jquery

I am using a tab panel WebPart that was given to me complete. The jQuery is repeating every-time the WebPart is edited so, the tabs repeat or get multiplied. I am using static information to populate the tabs. This does not happen when I am working in a publishing page unless I specifically click on the edit web part.

Comment: Without the code of the webpart it will be almost impossible to help you

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint adds a hidden control with a value which tells the client side code if the page or WebParts on that page are in `Edit` Mode.

In case of Wiki Pages, the id of the control is `_wikiPageMode` and in case of Publishing pages, it is `MSOLayout_InDesignMode`.

You can put your code inside an if statement like below to know if your page is in design mode and stop execution of code.

```
if($("#_wikiPageMode").val() "Edit" or "" ||
      $("#MSOLayout_InDesignMode").val() "1" or "") {

      //Your existing code here
}
```